# How to transfer a file between two remote servers using scp from a third, local machine in python

Tags: python, ssh, paramiko, scp

```
 I'm using paramiko to login in x machine then 
 after logged in machine x there are file in some path like 
 t="/abc/gfd/*" which 
 i want to copy to some path like 
 p=<username>@<machine-name/ip>:/dfg/hgf/kjh/.

cmd="pwd; scp {0} {1}".format(t,p)
pwd_of_machine_p="xyz"
cmd="xyz; scp {0} {1}".format(t,p)

then executing this cmd with paramiko obj like
client.exec_command(cmd)
which is not working .
```

when i do ls to this path "/dfg/hgf/kjh/" i get nothing in there.

Comment: During scp, it prompts for password, how are you handling that, seems because of this its not working.

Comment: yes for handling that , i'm passing password in "cmd" variable.
Like this cmd="pwd; scp {0} {1}".format(t,p)

Comment: I have tried passing password by stdin.write('pwd') that is also not working

Answer (score 0):

You can use below simple approach without using paramiko.

```
import os
os.system("scp FILE USER@DEST_MACHINE:PATH")
#e.g. os.system("scp file.txt sunilt@xx.xx.xx.xx:/path/")
```

But before that you need to generate an ssh key on the source machine and copy it to the destination machine,so that the scp automatically gets authenticated with your public ssh key and script doesn't ask for a password.

Information about generating and copying ssh key is @ [ssh_keygen_exapmple](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-ssh-keys--2)